# How to view 100k images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for an efficient JavaScript library or web app with which I can scroll through 10-100k images that I have sorted in a remote directory.

When I tried using plain HTML and img tags the browser would crash from memory pressure.

Comment: use some appear plugin(lazy loading), which will come in action when you scroll to button.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement a fake scrolling technique and load only a small number of pictures at the time. Like lazy loading but you remove older pictures as you scroll and you lazy load them in both directions, up and down.

You should also free img tag memory with a trick like this [LinkedIn Engineering Blog](http://engineering.linkedin.com/linkedin-ipad-5-techniques-smooth-infinite-scrolling-html5).

> UIWebView/Mobile Safari have strict limits for images. Our stream is full of big images, so we hit the limits very quickly. One option was to use the HTML5 Canvas element to draw images without running into memory issues. However, we found drawing very big images on canvas was slow, so we had to take another approach: whenever an image was swiped sufficiently off screen, we replaced the "src" attribute of the img tag with a very small image. This ensured that the memory used for rendering large images was freed up periodically. Also, we ensured that we did not introduce the empty image src attribute bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try lazy loading image? http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/

Image won't be loaded until the user scrolls to them.

Answer (score 1):

You can split it in many parts by making a Till layer and navigate trough like it was a map. You can use something like http://leafletjs.com/